# Inside rectangle box how to add svg and 2 textView in same line

Tags: react-native

```
   <View style={{ width: "100%",
                   minHeight: 100,
                     paddingHorizontal: 17}}> 
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            boxSizing: "borderBox",
            height: 56,
            width: 312,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#FF6D00",
            borderRadius: 2,
            marginTop: 24,
            paddingBottom: 10
            
          }}
        >
          <SVGImg width={10} height={10} />
          <Text h7 >
            Feature is not there for this particular page.
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this._onClickWhatisit()}
            >
              <Text h7>
                What is it 
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Text>
        </View>
 </View>
```

[image: this is what is coming from me]

Output what i need should be in same line image then text and all in center and left aligned.That react native image should come before Feature text with some space.

Comment: It's hard to completely understand your code without knowing what TextView is. Is it something you created then share that code. If its an import share the import.

Comment: I have updated that to text now.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a full example of what I think you want (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/great-waffles). Basically what I did was put two views next to each other as columns. Put the icon in one and the text in the other